# What does the singer sings (maybe in English) in the song "Mal Bicho"

Tags: lyrics

[This song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_6V-JTGn_M) is in Spanish, but it has a portion starting at 2:17, ([link to that part](https://youtu.be/P_6V-JTGn_M?t=137)) where it appears to be talking in English, But I do not understand any single word, since English is not my first language.

Can you transcribe the English portion of the lyrics (it is nowhere on Internet)? Or tell if it is not in English.

The song's name is "Mal bicho", by "Los fabulosos Cadillacs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those English lyrics are on the site [musicmatch.com](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Los-Fabulosos-Cadillacs/Mal-bicho) and they seem roughly correct:

> Mal bicho, your destiny's bad
> Mal bicho, voice marks your pride
> Mal bicho, a song that is played
> Mal bicho, is a song for always
>
> Mal bicho, who makes the wars
> Mal bicho, everything's lost
> Mal bicho, you love the man
> Mal bicho, and you don't give a damn